# Will another GPU speed up rendering?

Tags: gpu

I have spare 1060 as I recently upgraded to 3070 and was wondering if using both of them will improve rendering times

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. Rendering with wwo GPUs is faster than with one. They don't have to be the same kind (as long as you are not mixing AMD and Nvidia).